# Django rest You do not have permission to perform this action при создании схемы api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def get_auth():
auth = [
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('register', RegisterApiView),
    path('token/obtain/', TokenObtainPairView),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView),
]
return auth


def get_schema():
schema_url_patterns = [
    path('api/auth', include(get_auth())),
]

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    title='Auth Schema',
    url='/api/auth/',
    patterns=schema_url_patterns,
)
return schema_view


urlpatterns = [
  path('api/auth/', get_schema()),
]
```

Ошибка:

```
HTTP 403 Forbidden
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/coreapi+json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Починил все сам, ошибка была в методе get_auth(), я не добавил as_view():

```
def get_auth():
    auth = [
        path('', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
        path('register', RegisterApiView.as_view({'post': 'create'})),
        path('token/obtain/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
        path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
        ]
    return auth
```